# Christoffel symbols of a moduli of smooth curves

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hilbert-manifolds

**The Setting:** 
Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of all class $C^k$-curves into $\mathbb{R}$ with inner product: \begin{equation}
<f,g>:=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x)g'(x) e^{-x}dx
\end{equation}

Furthermore let $U$ be a Domain (simply connected and open subset) in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $F:U \rightarrow H$ (be a family of finitely parametrized $C^k$-curves into $\mathbb{R}$).

Let $M:=Im(F)\subseteq H$, be a finitely parametrized manifold.

---

My question is:
**(Christoffel symbols)**

Is there a general form for the Christoffel symbols of such a manifold; where the inner product is induced by the embedding of $M$ into $H$?

Comment: I guess that $F=G$?